# Facing issue while starting Controller in Docker

Tags: corda

Is there any updated version(Corda Version 1) of corda/corda-docker repository ?

I am facing issue while starting the container,
    1. create container command
    `docker create  --env --env CORDA_ORG=Controller --env CORDA_LOCALITY=London --env CORDA_COUNTRY=GB --env CORDA_P2P_PORT=10002 -p 0.0.0.0:10002:10002 --env CORDA_RPC_PORT=10003 --env EXTRA_ADV_SERVICE_ID="corda.notary.validating" --env CORDA_WEBADDRESS="0.0.0.0:10004" -p 10.103.1.4:10004:10004 --name Controller -t helloworldapp:latest`
    2. node.conf structure for Controller
    `basedir : "/etc/corda"
    p2pAddress : "$CORDA_HOST:$CORDA_P2P_PORT"
    rpcAddress : "$CORDA_HOST:$CORDA_RPC_PORT"
    h2port : 11000
    myLegalName : "O=Controller,L=London,C=GB"
    keyStorePassword : "cordacadevpass"
    trustStorePassword : "trustpass"
    extraAdvertisedServiceIds: [ "" ]
    useHTTPS : false
    devMode : true
    webAddress: "${CORDA_WEBADDRESS}"`

```
Is any configuration missing here?
Please help
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extraneous --env with no arguments just after create. I removed that and the following command succeeded for me: (note that I also changed the port binding after -p, you could put that back)

`docker create  --env CORDA_ORG=Controller --env CORDA_LOCALITY=London --env CORDA_COUNTRY=GB --env CORDA_P2P_PORT=10002 -p 0.0.0.0:10002:10002 --env CORDA_RPC_PORT=10003 --env EXTRA_ADV_SERVICE_ID="corda.notary.validating" --env CORDA_WEBADDRESS="0.0.0.0:10004" -p 10004 --name controller -t helloworldapp:latest`

I have started experimenting with using docker-compose for Corda, there is a (very basic) example here:

https://github.com/benabineri/corda-docker

You might like to join the public Corda slack and join the #corda-docker channel where we discuss using Corda in Docker:

http://slack.corda.net/